# web scraping python3.4 extract a paragraph

Tags: python, python-3.4

I use *requests* and *bs4* to scrap data from webpage
I have a string that contains few words from a paragraph in a webpage and I wish to know how to extract the whole paragraph containing it. If anyone knows how, please tell me! Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious way is to just iterate all the paragraphs and find the one that contains your words:

```
for p in soup.find_all('p'):
    if few_words in p.text:
        # found it, do something
```

Comment: That seems perfect thank you! But lets say the paragraph is in a span tag and not a <p> tag, how would I do that --- I did this *stringg = soup.find('span',{'id':'yfs_l84_aapl'}).text* but im looking for another way to do so

Comment: @bob: A `span` is not a `paragraph`. If what you want is to iterate all spans _and_ all paragraphs, you can just do that, or just all spans, or whatever, then of course you can do that.

Comment: @bob: More importantly, if you actually know the ID of the thing you're looking for, you should just be doing exactly what you're already doing. The only reason to do an iterative search like this is when you _don't_ know how to find the tag directly.

Comment: @abarnet alright, I will try both and I'll tell you what result I get Also, do you know if we can print a picture in python? Lets say I want to print a graphic

Comment: @bob Different questions, different posts. That's a must in SO. :)

Comment: @bob: You definitely need to ask that as a new question—although you should probably search first. And, more importantly, you need to make it a bit more detailed. Python can't print a picture in the sense of going out and hiring a print shop for you to produce a run from your negatives, nor can it display a graphical picture to an all-text console, but it certainly can display an image in a window in whatever GUI framework you're using or send a picture to the default system printer.

Comment: @bob Apart from that you also need to accept an answer if it has helped you! See this image http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png ... This will help others know that this has been answered!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some really simple cases that's good to have when webscraping. This partly answers your question, but since you have not given more info, my data and approach are assumptions at best.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
import re

html = """
<span>
    <div id="foo">
        The quick brown fox jumped
    </div>
    <p id="bar">
        over the lazy dog.
    </p>
</span>
"""

soup = bsoup(html)
soup.prettify()

# Find the div with id "foo" and get
# its inner text and print it.

foo = soup.find_all(id="foo")
f = foo[0].get_text()
print f

print "-" * 50

# Find the p with id "bar", get its
# inner text, strip all whitespace,
# and print it out.

bar = soup.find_all(id="bar")
b = bar[0].get_text().strip()
print b

print "-" * 50

# Find the word "lazy". Get its parent
# tag. If it's a p tag, get that p tag's
# parent, then get all the text inside that
# parent, strip all extra spaces, and print.
lazy = soup.find_all(text=re.compile("lazy"))
lazy_tag = lazy[0].parent

if lazy_tag.name == "p":
    lazy_grandparent = lazy_tag.parent
    all_text = lazy_grandparent.get_text()
    all_text = " ".join(all_text.split())
    print all_text
```

Result:

```
        The quick brown fox jumped

--------------------------------------------------
over the lazy dog.
--------------------------------------------------
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for para in request_soup.p.find_all(text=True,recursive=True):
```

you can use that to extract paragraphs even if there is any tag coming before the `<p>` tag